# Md-checkbox not showing up in angular2

Tags: angular, material-design

I am trying to show a checkbox in my angular2 application. But it's not showing up. What can be the possible reasons?

```
<md-checkbox [checked]="true">Unchecked</md-checkbox>
 <md-checkbox> Checkbox!</md-checkbox>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any error message in console?

Comment: No error in console @WangSteven

Comment: Do you follow the the "Augular Material getting started" | https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started to import MdCheckboxModule

Answer (score 0):

Import MaterialModule and MdCheckboxModule

`import {MaterialModule, MdCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material';`

Add metadata in @NgModule.

```
@NgModule({ 
             import: [MaterialModule, MdCheckboxModule]})
```

Comment: you should import MaterialModule after BrowserModule